# Нажатие на блок, после удаления любого элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при удаления любого элемента из списка, производилось автоматическое нажатие на  последний блок из списка ?

```
<ul>
  <li id="1" onclick="remove(this)">Items 1</li>
  <li id="2" onclick="remove(this)">Items 2 </li>
  <li id="3" onclick="remove(this)">Items 3 </li>
  <li id="Good" onclick="remove(this)">Items Good</li>
</ul>
```

```
function remove(element) {
    let items = element.id
    $(`#${items}`).remove()
  
}
```

Comment: Вопрос - зачем? Ведь тогда всё удалится. Нет?) Не проще ли тогда всё удалить сразу?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Нет, удалиться только те элементы, на которые нажал пользователь.

Comment: Нет. По итогу, если сделать клик на последний элемент - будет вызываться автоматом функция remove у него, а он будет в свою очередь вызывать клик на последнем элементе, который будет вызывать функцию remove у него, которая запустит триггер клика на последнем элементе......... суть думаю понятна

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Окей, нужно тогда при нажатие на любую из 3 первых элементов, чтобы он удалялся и с ним же удалялся последний

Answer (score 1):

```js
function remove(element) {
    let items = element.id
    $(`#${items}`).remove();
    $('ul li:last').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="1" onclick="remove(this);">Items 1</li>
  <li id="2" onclick="remove(this); ">Items 2 </li>
  <li id="3" onclick="remove(this);">Items 3 </li>
  <li id="Good">Items Good</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А можно ли внутри функции вызвать клик, который как раз удалит последний элемент ?

Comment: @9024872139  про рекурсию я уже написал вам под вопросом

Comment: ну зачем же jquery с инлайн onclick то мешать?

Comment: @teran это код автора, не мой) хочет смешивать - как хочет

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".items").on('click', "li:not(:last-child)", function(){
  $(this).remove();
  $(".items li:last-child").remove(); // если удалить любой последний
  //$("#good").remove()         // если надо удалить только #good
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="items">
  <li>Items 1</li>
  <li>Items 2 </li>
  <li>Items 3 </li>
  <li id="good">Items Good</li>
</ul>
```